# Adding two lists of characters

Tags: c++, list, operators, overriding, definition

In this problem, the user enters in two numbers.  Each number represents an integer, whose characters are stored into a list.  I need to modify the + operator, so that the program will take the two list characters, change them to ints, add them, and then change it back to a char list.  Its confusing I know, but hopefully the code will help clear things up:

```
class LongInt
{
public:
    friend LongInt operator+(const LongInt& x, const LongInt& y); //This function will add the value of the two integers which are represented by x and y's character list (val).

private:
    list<char> val; //the list of characters that represent the integer the user inputted

}
```

This is the header file for the LongInt class.  There are other parts too it such as a constructor, destructor, etc, but these are the only things that matter in this case.  I don't know how to go about writing the code for the operator+ definition in the implementation file.  Any ideas?

Comment: If this is homework then you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the list of chars to an int, you can do something like this:

```
std::list<char> digits;
int value = 0;
for(std::list<char>::iterator it = digits.begin(); 
    it != digits.end(); 
    ++it)
{
  value = value * 10 + *it - '0';
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the "* 10"?

Comment: I assume the numbers are in the decimal base, so the value is sum(digit(i) * 10 ^ i).

Comment: I apologize for the error with the reverse iterator. It should be a normal iterator. Start with the most significant digits and iterate to the least significant digit. Then multiply the current value with 10 and add the current digit.

Answer (score 3):

You would start the function something like this:

```
LongInt operator+(const LongInt& x, const LongInt& y) {
    // code goes here
}
```

This function definition would go *outside* the class definition (presumably in a `.cpp` implementation file).

Inside this function, you would add the parameters `x` and `y` using normal longhand addition (add pairs of corresponding digits, handle any carry, etc). Build up the result in a local `LongInt` object, and return the computed value from your `operator+()` function.

If it hasn't already been decided for you, you will need to decide whether the least significant digit comes *first* or *last* in your `val` list. Either way is valid, but one choice is likely to be easier to work with than the other (I'll let you decide which one).

Comment: is there a way to convert the list of characters to an array of characters? that way I can use Atoi() to convert an array of characters into one coherent int?

Comment: @Ctak: I'm just guessing here, but the name `LongInt` gives a clue that this class is probably intended to be used with numbers that are *too large* to fit into a regular C++ `int`. Therefore, calling `atoi()` won't be possible.